# I get this error "undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass" on trying to access a user by id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I am a newbie to rails, and I have already tried all solutions available on stackoverflow before.I am trying to access a user by id using localhost:3000/users/1. My code for user_controller is:

```
 class UsersController < ApplicationController
      def new
       @user=User.new
      end
      def index
       @users = User.all
      end
      def create
       @user = User.new(user_params)
      if @user.save
        redirect_to @user
      else
        @title = "Sign up"
        render 'new'
      end
    end
    private
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirmation,:email)
    end
    def show
       @user = @users.find(params[:id])
       @users=User.all
    end
  end

And my show.html.erb contains :
    <% provide(:title, @users.name ) %> 
    <div class="row">
    <aside class="span4">
    <section>
    <h1>
    <%= gravatar_for @user %>
    <%= @users.name  %>
    </h1>
    </section>
    </aside>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Take `show` action out of `private`. It is not a private method. That is why the variable, `@users` is nil. However, you don't need to even find `@users`, answer below shows that.
2. You are trying to call the method `name` (an attribute), on an array, `@users`. You need to call it on the object, `@user`.

---

**Side note**: there is also a predefined method, `name`, in Rails for an ActiveRecord::Relation (`User.all`). however, in the example you posted, your variable, `@users` was nil, so it wasn't getting this far. *But*, if your `show` action was not a private method, you would have experienced this:

```
$ User.all.name # or @users.name
# => 'User'

$ Post.all.name
# => 'Post'

$ User.first.name # or @user.name
# => 'John'
```

---

**Solution**

```
# show.html.erb
<%= @user.name %>

# users_controller
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def new
   @user = User.new
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      redirect_to @user
    else
      @title = "Sign up"
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirmation, :email)
  end 
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @kanika Justin Licata deserves the credit for this beautiful answer, don't forget to mark it as the solution ;-)